# django logging - only logs warning and error

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to configure django to capture debug and info log messages. I have two handlers. but they only seem to want to capture warning and error messages.

Can someone help point out the silly mistake i've probably made but can't figure out.

```
###  DJANGO LOGGING
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters':{
        'hc' : {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s\n%(message)s'
        },

    },
    'handlers': {
        'primary_log_handler':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': MAIN_LOG_FILE,
            # 5MB file size
            'maxBytes' : 5242880,
            'encoding' : 'utf-8',
            'backupCount' : 5,
            'formatter' : 'hc'
        },
        'debug_log_handler':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': DEBUG_LOG_FILE,
            # 5MB file size
            'maxBytes' : 5242880,
            'encoding' : 'utf-8',
            'backupCount' : 5,
            'formatter' : 'hc'
        },

    },
    'loggers': {        
        'some_module': {
            'handlers': ['primary_log_handler', 'debug_log_handler',],}
        'some_other_module': {
            'handlers': ['debug_log_handler',],},              
    },
}
```

Additionally, when instantiating loggers I do:

```
import logging
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and then in the relevant code I have:

```
logger.debug('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warn')
logger.error('err')
```

I'm on Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to configure at `loggers` level too:

```
'loggers': {        
    'some_module': {
        'handlers': ['primary_log_handler', 'debug_log_handler',],
    'level': 'DEBUG'}
    'some_other_module': {
        'handlers': ['debug_log_handler',],
     'level': 'DEBUG'},              
},
```

Comment: you are my savior

Comment: 'loggers': {        
    'some_module': {
        'handlers': ['primary_log_handler', 'debug_log_handler',],
    'level': 'DEBUG'},
    'some_other_module': {
        'handlers': ['debug_log_handler',],
     'level': 'DEBUG'},              
},

Answer (score 2):

Simply change

```
'level': 'DEBUG'
```

To the log level you desire.

Comment: i am trying to capture debug and info messages. the loggers only captures error and warning messages right now. it totally ignores debug and info. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler",},
        "file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "log.django",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "some_module": {
            "handlers": ["primary_log_handler", "debug_log_handler",],
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "some_other_module": {"handlers": ["debug_log_handler",], "level": "DEBUG"},
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late, but I got the same problem. Check the correct LOGGER_NAME in the configuration solved it:

###### settings.py

```
 LOGGER_NAME = 'some_module.{}'
```

Hope this help somebody else.